# Using AND in a DELETE FROM statement

Tags: mysql, sql, delete-row

I'm having trouble using the AND operator in a DELETE FROM statement. I can get the query to run successfully, but it's not affecting any rows. If I edit the query, get rid of the AND operator and its conditional, it will run successfully and delete that one row. Here's the example I'm working with.

```
DELETE FROM classicmodels.employees 
WHERE
    employeeNumber = 1706
    AND employeeNumber = 1707
```

Why is my query not deleting the rows? How would I fix this? I appreciate any help with this.

Comment: You need to use `OR`, not `AND`.

Comment: Barmar's probably got it covered but, if not, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query. (I typed 'Barmar' wrong, but my phone corrected it. Proof that I'm on here too much.)

Comment: Think of it more like this - the database will go through each row and check if the _whole_ WHERE part of your query is true for that row. A single row can't be both 1706 and 1707 on the same field.

Comment: That's a good way of thinking about it Luke. Rookie mistake

Comment: @NickT No problem, easy mistake to make - happy coding! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AND` means a row has to satisfy both conditions (think about how you use it when matching different columns). It's not possible for the row to have two different `employeeNumber` values.

If you want to delete both employees, you should use `OR`, not `AND`.

Even better is to use `IN`: `WHERE employeeNumber IN (106, 107)`

Answer (score 1):

You must have meant `OR`

```
DELETE 
FROM classicmodels.employees 
WHERE employeeNumber = 1706 OR employeeNumber = 1707;
```

Can also be written as

```
DELETE 
FROM classicmodels.employees 
WHERE employeeNumber IN (1706,1707)
```

Comment: Thanks Gandalf. I'll use that second query from now on. That'll should lead to less confusion down the road